# Is the einbein the same thing as or related to the threading lapse function?

Tags: general-relativity, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, string-theory

If I understand correctly the einbein can be understood as the component of a one-dimensional metric, along a particle worldline. I'm not so sure of writing it out explicitly, but this seems like it might be: $$-c^2 d\tau^2 = - c^2 e^2 dt^2 \ .$$ To me this seems mathematically and conceptually close to the idea of a threading lapse function.

Comment: Does this help: @ https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4188/ ?

Comment: Thanks, I have seen that particular thread, as well as https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/211350/92181 but I'm still not sure if (or in what way) I am conflating separate ideas or not.